# Public SBT Plugin Repo seems to be broken

Tags: scala, sbt

Currently all our builds are failing because that are not able to resolve plugins from the public SBT Plugin Repo. We get the following error:

> [warn]    Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
>   [warn]      com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.4.0 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
>   [warn]      com.github.gseitz:sbt-release:1.0.0 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)

The SBT [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html) list the predefined repos. **The link for the sbt plugins results in a 404.** I think some kind of redirect mechanism is broken.

I know that the actual artifacts are hosted on bintray. Therefore i tried to point my build directly to this repo, but this does seem to help. I added following to my **project/plugins.sbt**:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url(
  "fix-sbt-plugin-releases",
   url("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(
   Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Does anyone know a fix how to circumvent this?

Comment: Looks like the sbt folks know about it: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2125 (and are presumably working on a fix)

Answer (score 1):

Will not help you right now, but you might want to consider it for the future:

You could use something like Artifactory to mirror all of your dependencies in your local network.

You can than configure Artifactory as a proxy and would only be disappointed when you try to download a new dependency during down time (which should be pretty unlikely).

Makes dependency resolving faster, too.